# Generador de PDF Dompdf con estilos css Bootstrap en Laravel 5.5

Tags: laravel, dompdf

Tengo problemas con DomPDF y Bootstrap. Estoy utilizando Laravel 5.5 como framework PHP y agregué el servicio de DomPDF. En mi controller cree una función que me permite crear el pdf:

```
public function ImprimirAprobacionesPDF($id){

        $reportes = $this->reportesRepository->findWithoutFail($id);

        $especialistas = Personas::where('especialista', 1)->get();

        $solucion = Soluciones::where('reporte_id', $id)->get()->first();

        $aprobacion = Aprobaciones::where('solucion_id', $solucion->id)->get()->first();


        $pdf = PDF::loadView('pdf.show_solucionados', compact('reportes', 'especialistas', 'solucion', 'aprobacion'));

        return $pdf->download('listado.pdf');
    }
```

Y en la vista que toma dompdf para generar el pdf, estoy llamando a mi bootstrap de la siguiente forma:

```
<!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->

<link href="{{ asset('asset/css/bootstrap.min.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">
```

Ahora bien, cuando intento generar el pdf me da el siguiente error:

```
fopen(C:\xampp\htdocs\sis-report\storage\fonts/\85dd72754417df6fd60253947544be57.ufm): failed to open stream: No such file or directory
```

Como puedo solucionar este error para poder utilizar los css de mi proyecto.

Comment: solo crea una carpeta llamada `fonts` dentro de la carpeta storage de laravel

Comment: muchas gracias, hice lo que me propuso y me soluciono el problema